# To extend string (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to extend the string `keyCode` repeating its values. So, for example, the string `"abcd"` becomes `"abcdabcdabcd..."` according to the value of varialbe `lengthSC`.

I don't understand why in this function, the replication is done always 4 times (so the result is `"abcdabcdabcdabcd")` nonetheless the value of `lengthSC` variable?

```
int copyElements (char keyCode[500], int lengthSC, int i)
{

    for(i=0; i<lengthSC; i++)
    {
        strncat(keyCode, keyCode, lengthSC);
        printf("%c", keyCode[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for the help! :)

Comment: "the replication is done always 4 times" How did you determine this? Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this `printf` call? Also, why is `i` a parameter?

Comment: From [the documentation of strncat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat): "*The behavior is undefined if the source and destination objects overlap.*" You can't concatenate a string to itself!

Comment: Hi archer! Please check how to submit a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps us and also you who will benefit from isolating the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , with the printf I'm trying to see if the string are been extended with the copied values. Concerning the "4 times", I'm sorry. I misspoke: I don't undestand why my IDE copy the text until 16 values (without consider the value of lengthSC variable)

Comment: @Kevin ok, thanks :)

Comment: @sidyll Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

`strncat(keyCode, keyCode, lengthSC);` results in *undefined behavior*. The source and destination are not allowed to overlap. (Ref: C11 7.24.3.2/2: "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.")

It's not entirely clear what the original function is supposed to do. It has parameters that are ignored and a return type but no return value. The following code will repeat the string contents up to a specified length and append a null terminator. It will also truncate the string if longer than the desired length, but leave an empty string unchanged:

```
void copyElements (char *keyCode, size_t lengthSC)
{
    size_t a, b;

    // Find end of string up to maximum length lengthSC.
    for (b = 0; b < lengthSC && keyCode[b]; b++)
        ;
    
    if (b != 0)
    {
        // String is not empty.
        // Extend the string up to lengthSC, copying from the beginning.
        a = 0;
        while (b < lengthSC)
        {
            keyCode[b++] = keyCode[a++];
        }
    }

    // append null terminator
    keyCode[b] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed overlapping could be a problem as suggested by others, try to use a temporary string, here's a little example you can adapt to your code:

```
char keyCode[500]="Abc";
char tmp[3];
int lengthSC=5;
int i;
strcpy(tmp, keyCode);

for(i=0; i<lengthSC; i++)
{
    strncat(keyCode, tmp, lengthSC);
    
    printf("%s", keyCode);
    printf("\n");
    
}
```

Output is

```
AbcAbc                                                                                                                                        
AbcAbcAbc                                                                                                                                     
AbcAbcAbcAbc                                                                                                                                  
AbcAbcAbcAbcAbc                                                                                                                               
AbcAbcAbcAbcAbcAbc
```

Comment: You have to change tmp [3] to tmp [4] to get your real output

Comment: Thanks so much :)